# Column width not working on 2nd & subsequent tables on a page

Tags: tabulator

I have a very simple single page with three tables on it (MVC):

```html
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

<script src="~/Scripts/grids.js"></script>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<ul id="tabs" class="uk-tab" data-uk-tab="{connect:'#divMenu'}" style="text-transform: uppercase;" uk-switcher>
    <li id="tabPressureUlcer" class="uk-active"><a href="#" id="PressureUlcer">Pressure Ulcer</a></li>
    <li id="tabMoistureDamage"><a href="#" id="MoistureDamage">Moisture Damage</a></li>
    <li id="tabTissueViability"><a href="#" id="TissueViability">Tissue Viability</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="divMenu" class="uk-switcher uk-margin">
    <li><div id="divPressureUlcer"></div></li>
    <li><div id="divMoistureDamage"></div></li>
    <li><div id="divTissueViability"></div></li>
</ul>
```

(The Tabulator files are included in the layout page)

This is the grid.js code:

```js
    var puTable, mdTable, tvTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewHeight = $("main").height() - 120;

    var getDate = function (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
        var value = cell.getValue();
        var myDate = moment(value);
        return myDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    }

    var dateEditor = function (cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
        //cell - the cell component for the editable cell
        //onRendered - function to call when the editor has been rendered
        //success - function to call to pass the successfuly updated value to Tabulator
        //cancel - function to call to abort the edit and return to a normal cell

        //create and style input
        var cellValue = moment(cell.getValue(), "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            input = document.createElement("input");

        input.setAttribute("type", "date");

        input.style.padding = "4px";
        input.style.width = "100%";
        input.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

        input.value = cellValue;

        onRendered(function () {
            input.focus();
            input.style.height = "100%";
            input.style.fontSize = "14px";
            input.style.fontFamily = "arial"; 5
        });

        function onChange() {
            if (input.value != cellValue) {
                success(moment(input.value, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
            } else {
                cancel();
            }
        }

        //submit new value on blur or change
        input.addEventListener("blur", onChange);

        //submit new value on enter
        input.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                onChange();
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                cancel();
            }
        });

        return input;
    };

    var selectList = function (what) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Lookup/GetLookup",
            data: {
                what: what
            },
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            select: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                values = result;
            },
            error: function (e) {
                writeLog("Getting Details: " + e.responseText);
            }
        });

        return values;
    }

    puTable = new Tabulator("#divPressureUlcer", {
        layout: "fitData",
        history: false,
        addRowPos: "top",
        initialSort: [{ column: "ID", dir: "desc" }],
        height: viewHeight,
        selectable: 1,
        pagination: "local",
        paginationSize: 20,
        ajaxURL: "/Lookup/GetPUData",
        ajaxResponse: function (lookup, params, response) {
            return response;
        },
        columns: [
            { title: "ID", field: "ID", visible: false },
            {
                title: "MPI", field: "MPI", headerFilter: "input", sorter: "string", editor: "input", editorParams: {
                    elementAttributes: {
                        maxlength: "6",
                        mask: "999999"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                title: "NHS #", field: "NHSNumber", headerFilter: "input", sorter: "string", editor: "input", editorParams: {
                    elementAttributes: {
                        maxlength: "10",
                        mask: "9999999999"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                title: "Patient Name",
                columns: [
                    { title: "First", sorter: "string", editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Last", sorter: "string", editor: "input" },
                ]
            },
            {
                title: "Ward", field: "Ward", sorter: "string", editor: "select", editorParams:
                    function (cell) {
                        var values = {};
                        valuesList = selectList("Ward");

                        for (var key in valuesList) {
                            values[valuesList[key]["Text"]] = valuesList[key]["Text"];
                            i = 1;
                        }

                        return { values: values };
                    }
            },
            {
                title: "Types of Referral",
                columns: [
                    {
                        title: "First", field: "TypeOfReferral", sorter: "string", editor: "select", editorParams:
                            function (cell) {
                                var values = {};
                                valuesList = selectList("ReferralType1");

                                for (var key in valuesList) {
                                    values[valuesList[key]["Text"]] = valuesList[key]["Text"];
                                    i = 1;
                                }

                                return { values: values };
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Second", field: "TypeOfReferral2", sorter: "string", editor: "select", editorParams:
                            function (cell) {
                                var values = {};
                                valuesList = selectList("ReferralType2");

                                for (var key in valuesList) {
                                    values[valuesList[key]["Text"]] = valuesList[key]["Text"];
                                    i = 1;
                                }

                                return { values: values };
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Third", field: "TypeOfReferral3", sorter: "string", editor: "select", editorParams:
                            function (cell) {
                                var values = {};
                                valuesList = selectList("ReferralType3");

                                for (var key in valuesList) {
                                    values[valuesList[key]["Text"]] = valuesList[key]["Text"];
                                    i = 1;
                                }

                                return { values: values };
                            }
                    },
                ]
            },
            { title: "Hospital Aquired?", field: "HospitalAquired", sorter: "string", editor: "input" },
            { title: "New or POA", field: "NewOrPOA", sorter: "string", editor: "select", editorParams: { values: ["NEW", "POA", ""] } },
            {
                title: "Transfer From", field: "TransferFrom", sorter: "string", editor: "select", editorParams:
                    function (cell) {
                        var values = {};
                        valuesList = selectList("Transferred");

                        for (var key in valuesList) {
                            values[valuesList[key]["Text"]] = valuesList[key]["Text"];
                            i = 1;
                        }

                        return { values: values };
                    }
            },
            {
                title: "Anatomical Sites", field: "AnatomicalSites", sorter: "string", editor: "select", editorParams:
                    function (cell) {
                        var values = {};
                        valuesList = selectList("PU_Site");

                        for (var key in valuesList) {
                            values[valuesList[key]["Text"]] = valuesList[key]["Text"];
                            i = 1;
                        }

                        return { values: values };
                    }
            },
            { title: "Type Of Wound", field: "TypeOfWound", sorter: "string", editor: "input" },
            { title: "Vac Application", field: "VacApplication", sorter: "string", editor: "input" },
            {
                title: "Category", field: "Category", sorter: "string", editor: "select", editorParams:
                    function (cell) {
                        var values = {};
                        valuesList = selectList("Category");

                        for (var key in valuesList) {
                            values[valuesList[key]["Text"]] = valuesList[key]["Text"];
                            i = 1;
                        }

                        return { values: values };
                    }
            },
            { title: "Date Of Referral", field: "DateOfReferral", sorter: "date", align: "center", formatter: getDate, editor: dateEditor },
            { title: "Date Seen", field: "DateSeen", sorter: "date", align: "center", formatter: getDate, editor: dateEditor },
            { title: "Date Of Discharge", field: "DateOfDischarge", sorter: "date", align: "center", formatter: getDate, editor: dateEditor },
            { title: "Date Of District Nurse Referral", field: "DateOfDistrictNurseReferral", sorter: "date", align: "center", formatter: getDate, editor: dateEditor },
            { title: "District Nurse Referral Completed", field: "DistrictNurseReferralCompleted", sorter: "string", editor: "input" },
            { title: "Date GP Informed", field: "DateGPInformed", sorter: "date", align: "center", formatter: getDate, editor: dateEditor },
            { title: "MDR", field: "MDR", sorter: "string", editor: "select", editorParams: { values: ["YES", "NO"] } },
            { title: "Severity Of Harm", field: "SeverityOfHarm", sorter: "string", editor: "input" },
            { title: "Lapses In Care", field: "LapsesInCare", sorter: "string", editor: "input" },
            { title: "Comments", field: "Comments", editor: "textarea" },
        ]
    });

    mdTable = new Tabulator("#divMoistureDamage", {
        layout: "fitData",
        history: false,
        addRowPos: "top",
        initialSort: [{ column: "ID", dir: "desc" }],
        height: viewHeight,
        selectable: 1,
        pagination: "local",
        paginationSize: 20,
        ajaxURL: "/Lookup/GetMDData",
        ajaxResponse: function (lookup, params, response) {
            return response;
        },
        columns: [
            { title: "ID", field: "ID", visible: false },
            { title: "MPI", field: "MPI", headerFilter: "input", sorter: "string" },
            { title: "NHS #", field: "NHSNumber", headerFilter: "input", sorter: "string" },
            {
                title: "Patient Name",
                columns: [
                    { title: "First", sorter: "string" },
                    { title: "Last", sorter: "string" }
                ]
            },
            { title: "Week Commencing", field: "WeekCommencing", sorter: "date", align: "center", formatter: getDate, editor: dateEditor },
            { title: "Ward", field: "Ward", sorter: "string" },
            { title: "Type of Referral", field: "Type", sorter: "string" },
            { title: "Severity", field: "Severity", sorter: "string" },
            { title: "Site", field: "Site", sorter: "string" },
            { title: "New or POA", field: "NewOrPOA", sorter: "string", editor: "select", editorParams: { values: ["NEW", "POA", ""] } },
            { title: "Entered", field: "Entered", sorter: "date", align: "center", formatter: getDate, editor: dateEditor },
            { title: "Occured", field: "Occured", sorter: "string" },
            { title: "Datix", field: "Datix", sorter: "string", editor: "select", editorParams: { values: ["YES", "NO"] } }
        ]
    });

    tvTable = new Tabulator("#divTissueViability", {
        layout: "fitData",
        history: false,
        addRowPos: "top",
        initialSort: [{ column: "ID", dir: "desc" }],
        height: viewHeight,
        selectable: 1,
        ajaxURL: "/Lookup/GetTVData",
        ajaxResponse: function (lookup, params, response) {
            return response;
        },
        ajaxError: function (error) {
            i = 1;
        },
        columns: [
            { title: "ID", field: "ID", visible: false },
            { title: "MPI", field: "MPI", headerFilter: "input", sorter: "string" },
            { title: "NHS #", field: "NHSNumber", headerFilter: "input", sorter: "string" },
            {
                title: "Patient Name",
                columns: [
                    { title: "First", sorter: "string" },
                    { title: "Last", sorter: "string" }
                ]
            },
            { title: "Ward", field: "Ward", sorter: "string" },
            { title: "Date Seen", field: "DateSeen", sorter: "date", align: "center", formatter: getDate, editor: dateEditor },
            {
                title: "Referral Types",
                columns: [
                    { title: "First", field: "ReferralType1", sorter: "string" },
                    { title: "Second", field: "ReferralType2", sorter: "string" },
                    { title: "Third", field: "ReferralType3", sorter: "string" }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: "Wound Types",
                columns: [
                    { title: "First", field: "TypeOfWound", sorter: "string" },
                    { title: "NPWT", field: "NPWT", sorter: "string" },
                    { title: "Third", field: "TypeOfWound2", sorter: "string" }
                ]
            },
            { title: "Date of Referral", field: "DateOfReferral", sorter: "date", align: "center", formatter: getDate, editor: dateEditor },
            { title: "Photo", field: "Photo", sorter: "string" },
            { title: "Consent", field: "Consent", sorter: "string" },
            { title: "LDT", field: "LDT", sorter: "string" },
            { title: "Comments", field: "Comments" }
        ]
    });
});
```

And this is what happens:

[image: First Table]

[image: Second and subsequent tables]

I can't figure out what's happening at all! Investigating the columns on the 2nd table in Dev Tools shows that they have no width set.

Any and all help will be gratefully received!

Paul

edit: it seems to be something to do with the vDOM maybe? I've set all three tables as paginated and on the 2nd & 3rd, moving to the next page clears the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here (coz I dont have a full working example from your code), but I've seen similar things on my own code when a Tabulator is created in a <div> that is not rendered until later (like selecting your "MOISTURE DAMAGE", which I assumes changes the style.display on the <div> ?).

If I remember correctly, I called a Tabulator.redraw(true) on the newly rendered table to get it to recalc() all the widths now that it is was visible and render properly.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has a similar problem, RTFM works wonders :-D

The grids were hidden when first created, so in a similar vein to Michael's suggestion I simply instantiated them only when the tab is first clicked and it's content div is visible.